# Extended Event in Anaysis Service 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008, extended-events

Is Extended Event supported in Anaysis Service 2008? If yes, can someone provide me XMLA script for creating extended events?

Comment: Please tag SSAS, So that it will reach to right group. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Extended events were introduced with SSAS in SQL Server 2012 as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/analysisservices/using-extended-events-with-sql-server-analysis-services-2016-ctp-2-3?).